# AJAX pre-populated drop down menu

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

This is a bit complicated so bear with me:

On FORM.php, I have 2 drop down menus:

`Plant type` drop down that allows the user to select 'Plant type'.

`Plant sub-type` drop down that via AJAX and a call to the database presents multiple choices for 'Plant sub-type'.

AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getXMLHTTP() {
        var xmlhttp = false;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e1) {
                    xmlhttp = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getPlantSubtype(strURL) {
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('plant_subtype_div').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>
```

That works perfectly and when I submit, values are saved in the DB and shown on a table below the form.

Now the user wants to edit this entry, clicking on 'Edit' adjacent to the table cell with the info.

Values for 'Plant type' and 'Plant sub-type' are passed via `$_POST` to EDIT.php.

EDIT.php code (using Smarty tags):

```
<select name="plant_type" onchange="getPlantSubtype('plant_subtype.php?plant_type='+this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="{$plant_type}">
        {$plant_type}
    </option>

    <option value="" disabled="disabled">
        ---
    </option>

    <option value="1">
        Tomato
    </option>

    <option value="2">
        Carrot
    </option>
</select>

<div id="plant_subtype_div">
    <select name="plant_subtype">
        <option selected="selected" value="{$plant_subtype}">
            {$plant_subtype}
        </option>

        <option value="" disabled="disabled">
            ---
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

On EDIT.php both drop down menus show the correct values.

But when I click on `Plant sub-type` drop down the multiple choices are not available.

That's because the form was already pre-populated with `$_POST` and `onChange` hasn't happened yet.

How do I make `Plant sub-type` drop down show its choices when EDIT.php is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is just to call `getPlantSubtype('plant_subtype.php?plant_type={$plant_type}')` on the page load.

For example (on the bottom of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    getPlantSubtype('plant_subtype.php?plant_type={$plant_type}')
</script>
```

A Better option would be to fetch the subtypes from the same place `plant_subtype.php` fetches them from (cache, db) and populate the option values.

Comment: scrum meister - unfortunately that didn't work -- I think the issue is that the code you sent is still linked to `onChange` -- how do we get it out of there and link it to page load?

Comment: scrum meister - BEAUTIFUL! works perfectly -- thanks for the help, much appreciated!